# Why does the content in a Streamlit widget disappear when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm building a chat application using Streamlit and OpenAI. When I click the "STOP" button, the result of the chat (displayed in res_box) disappears, which is not the desired behavior. I want the results to persist even after the "STOP" button is clicked. How can I make this happen?

```
import openai
import streamlit as st

# Set OpenAI API Key
openai.api_key = "<API-KEY>"

# Header for the application
st.subheader("AI Assistant : Streamlit + OpenAI: `stream` *argument*")

# Text input for user
user_input = st.text_input("You: ", placeholder = "Ask me anything ...", key="input")

# Initialize 'stop_pressed' and 'result' in session state if they don't exist
if 'stop_pressed' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['stop_pressed'] = False
if 'result' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state['result'] = ""

# Create an empty box to display results
res_box = st.empty()

# Submit button action
if st.button("Submit", type="primary"):

    # Reset result to an empty string
    result = ""

    # Stop button action
    if st.button("STOP", key="stop"):
        st.session_state['stop_pressed'] = True

    # Separate different parts of the interface
    st.markdown("----")

    report = []

    try:
        # Create a chat completion with OpenAI
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model='gpt-4', messages=[{"role": "assistant", "content": user_input}],
                                            temperature = 0,
                                            stream = True)
        # Iterate through responses from OpenAI
        for resp in response:
            report.append(resp["choices"][0]["delta"]["content"])
            result = "".join(report).strip()
            result = result.replace("\n", "")
            # Store the result in the session state
            st.session_state['result'] = result
            # Display result so far
            res_box.markdown(f'*{result}*') 

            if st.session_state['stop_pressed']:
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        response.close()

# If there is a result, display it
if st.session_state["result"] != "":
    res_box.markdown(f'*{st.session_state["result"]}*')

# Separate different parts of the interface
st.markdown("----")
```

Inspired by: https://medium.com/@avra42/how-to-stream-output-in-chatgpt-style-while-using-openai-completion-method-b90331c15e85

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit's execution model reruns your script from start to finish whenever you interact with a widget. This means that when someone presses the "stop" button, the app reruns. It looks like you're already saving the chat result to `st.session_state`, so all you need to do is add a line to retrieve the chat result from session state and write it to the UI when the app first renders (or when it reruns after someone interacts with a widget).